# new tabs for different files

Tags: xcode

I need to use Xcode like a general purpose editor. For example I need to open file .txt, .project, etc etc… If I open one file at time all go well, but I need to put other files in new tabs.

I tried

```
cmd+t
```

but the new tab has exactly the same text as the first tab…
and if I open an other file with a double click, it open a new Windows and not a new tab… 
there is a solution?

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Command+T will open up a new tab with the same file, then you can navigate to a new file and open that one up in either tab.

XCode will not be able to assume what file you want to open in the new tab and it doesn't want to open an empty tab, so it opens the current file in the new tab.

Comment: I cant navigate to an other file.. if I do File->open->differentFile.txt, it will open that new file in a new window and not in the tab

Comment: I believe that is most likely because the file is not in your project. Try adding the file to the project then opening it.

Comment: @Jsdodgers: That's what he means, he doesn't want to have to create projects to open multiple files that may not be related in the same window.

Comment: In that case, I have been able to get it to work by dragging the file onto the little bar between the tab bar and the file window.

Comment: I know its not the most optimal solution but its the best I could think of.

Comment: the best? I cannot open two different file in two different tabs on the same windowd..I cant belive it xD

Comment: Did you try the dragging idea?

Comment: Actually, @Jsdodgers' drag-and-drop solution works surprisingly well (who knew?). Xcode has never claimed to be a "general purpose" editor (you'd probably be better served using TextMate, SublimeText or KomodoEdit if that's what you need). It is a project/workspace-based IDE that relies on a standard directory and file structure to do what it does best -- keeping track of all the files (and the relationships among them) to produce a working software package. It was never intended to be used to create a collection of unrelated files, so using it to do so can lead to madness.

Answer (score 0):

For XCode 10, right click on the file, select *Open in New Tab*.

[image]

I don't know when it was added.